# Lazy Loading mvc3

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3

I have Order - Customers table

i am using lazyloading for pulling order-customers information.

```
var ordercustomer = db.Orders.Include("customers").Where(c.orderid == id);
```

so i have pulled a ORDER WITH RELATED CUSTOMERS

I HAVE CUSTOMERID ,CUSTOMERCITY VALUES from the Form values

NOW MY TASK IS to check whether customerid and customercity exist in the
                ordercustomer (result of the linq)

how would the linq query looks like?

Comment: You might do better to provide more code sample. For example, where does `id` come from in your where clause, somewhere in your model, controller? Also, use the markdown StackOverflow provides. For example, code is done by 4 spaces of indentation. I'll edit your post to show an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're asking for something like this:

```
db.Orders.Where(c => c.orderid == id)
    .Select(c => c.customers.Any(
        cu => cu.customerid == customerid && cu.customercity == customercity))
    .Single();
```

This will produce a true or false value that tells you whether the given order has a customer associated with it that has the given ID and city. If the order doesn't exist, an exception will be thrown.

On a side note, when use use `.Include`, that is called *eager* loading. It is the opposite of *lazy* loading. Also, note that your original query doesn't actually have any of the customers loaded yet because you haven't evaluated it by calling `.ToList` or something similar. In the query I've provided, you aren't required to use `.Include` because there is no reason to load all the Customer data into memory, when the database can do this work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You might not need a LINQ query, but @StriplingWarrior has it in his answer.

I can't guess exactly how your form values exist, because you didn't tell us, but I will assume it's in a [view model](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2009/10/25/asp.net-mvc-view-model-patterns.aspx) as described below. If it isn't, it probably should be ;)

```
public class OrderCustomerViewModel
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerCity { get; set; }
}
```

I will also assume this logic is happening inside a controller action. It's probably not the best place, but you *could* put it there.

```
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CheckCustomer(OrderCustomerViewModel vm)
    {
        var ordercustomer = db.Orders.Include("Customers").Where(c.orderid == id);
        bool customerFound = false;
        foreach(var customer in ordercustomer.Customers)
        {
            if(customer.CustomerID == vm.CustomerID &&
               customer.CustomerCity == vm.CustomerCity)

                customerFound = true;
        }

        // now, do whatever you need to with customerFound
        ViewBag.CustomerFound = customerFound;
        return View();
    }
}
```

Please note that I've modified your `Orders` and `Customers` collections to be capitalized.